# How to split a string into its character vector?

Tags: r, string, character

In R I have a string like this:

```
'hello'
```

How do I convert it to a character vector like that:

```
[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"
```

Answer (score 3):

With `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_split("hello","")[[1]]
[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"
```

Found another possible solution, although this is probably the worst approach:

```
substring("hello", seq(1,nchar("hello")), seq(1,nchar("hello")))
[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"
```

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be the most performant solution, this works as expected:

```
> unlist(strsplit('hello', ''))
[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"
```

See the documentation of [unlist](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/unlist) and [strsplit](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/strsplit) for further options.